# dataTables header alignment issues

Tags: javascript, jquery, css, datatables

I'm using dataTables for my application and its awesome, but I do have a small problem: fnAdjustColumnSizing function only works when I resize the browser. Lets say I don't resize the browser and any additional scroll bars (i.e  body scroll) bar pops up or any additional scroll bar pops up because I have the overflow set as auto for some  within my page the header does not align with the columns.  I'm including the image so you can see whats going on.

[image]

As you see in the image above, the scroll bar on the right causes the alignment issues. I have to re size the window to fix this problem every time its not doing it automatically how it works when I re size the the browser.  Any suggestions?

Javascript:

```
$(document).ready(function() {
var oTable = $('#myTable').dataTable({
    "sScrollY" : "400px",
    "bPaginate" : false,
    "aaSorting": []
});
    $(window).bind('resize', function () {
        oTable.fnAdjustColumnSizing();
    } );
});
```

CSS:

```
#summary{
overflow-y: auto;
overflow-x: auto;
}
table.display {
font-family:arial;
background-color: #FFFFFF;
margin:0px 0pt 0px;
text-align: left;
position: relative;
border: 2px #808080;
border-style: outset;

}
table.display thead th {
background-color: #FFFFFF;
border: 1px #808080;
border-style: groove;
font-size: 14px;
font-family: Arial;
font-weight: normal;
text-align: center;
background-position: center bottom;
cursor: hand;
position: relative;

}

table.display tbody {
color: #3d3d3d;
font-size: 12px;
font-weight: normal;
vertical-align: center;
text-align:left;    
font-family: Arial;




}
#export{
cursor: hand;
}
.highlight td {background: #FFFFFF;}
.cbx{
width: 13px;
height: 13px;
}
#table1{
height:600px; 
overflow:auto;
}
```

Comment: You could make sure the scrollbar is always there... body { overflow-y: scroll; }

Answer (score 1, accepted):

After adding "sScrollX" : "100%", to my javascript it works fine for me now!.

Answer (score 0):

Updating this in dataTables.fixedHeader.js from **fixed** to **auto** worked for me.

[image]

**Note**: It is probably not a good idea to update the *dataTables.fixedHeader.js* directly as I have for this example.